# Python project throws a keyerror

Tags: python, keyerror

I'm working on my Python assignment and am trying to convert strings into the ICAO letter codes.  However, whenever the first loop of the program ends, it throws a KeyError and refuses to continue to ask the user if they want to translate another string.  Could anyone help me with this?  Thanks.

```py
while True:
    ICAOInput = raw_input("Please enter a string: ")
    inputToUpper = ICAOInput.upper()

    def buildCodeArray():
        ICAOArray = {
            "A": "Alpha",
            "B": "Bravo",
            "C": "Charlie",
            "D": "Delta",
            "E": "Echo",
            "F": "Foxtrot",
            "G": "Golf",
            "H": "Hotel",
            "I": "India",
            "J": "Juliet",
            "K": "Kilo",
            "L": "Lima",
            "M": "Mike",
            "N": "November",
            "O": "Oscar",
            "P": "Papa",
            "Q": "Quebec",
            "R": "Romeo",
            "S": "Sierra",
            "T": "Tango",
            "U": "Uniform",
            "V": "Victor",
            "W": "Whiskey",
            "X": "X-ray",
            "Y": "Yankee",
            "Z": "Zulu",
            " ": " "}

        return ICAOArray


    def translateString(string, array):
        inputStr = ""

        punctList = "~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={[}]\|;:<,>.?/''"
        for x in string:
            if x not in punctList:
                inputStr = inputStr + x
        inputList = list(inputStr)

        for i in inputList:
            inputList = [array[letter] for letter in inputList]
            print (inputList)

    ICAOArray = buildCodeArray()
    translateString(inputToUpper, buildCodeArray())
    loop = raw_input("Would you like to translate another String?  Please press 'Y' to restart or another key to end.")
    if loop.upper() == "Y":
        continue
    print "Bye"
    break
```

And here is the KeyError:

```sh
Please enter a string: Hello
['Hotel', 'Echo', 'Lima', 'Lima', 'Oscar']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/technologyspotlight/Desktop/Assignment 2.py", line 52, in <module>
    translateString(inputToUpper, buildCodeArray())
  File "/Users/technologyspotlight/Desktop/Assignment 2.py", line 48, in translateString
    inputList = [array[letter] for letter in inputList]
KeyError: 'Hotel'
```

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback that includes the KeyError for context?

Comment: @CoryKramer Edited to post, thanks

Comment: [Python 2 is dead](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). You should learn python 3 since you're learning.

Comment: The function `buildCodeArray` seems pointless, calling it twice and never using the result of the first call even more so.

Comment: A few other observations: 1. You can define your functions outside the loop. 2. You do `ICAOArray = buildCodeArray()` but never use `ICAOArray`. 3. You don't need a function `buildCodeArray()` because it always returns the same value. Just use the value instead.

Comment: The `for i in inputList:` loop is strange – why is it a loop? Also (strong hint), reusing variables for multiple purposes (like you're doing with `inputList`, using it both as input and result) is a pretty reliable way to get bugs.

Comment: 4. You do the whole `for x in string` loop to keep appending `x` to `inputString` and then convert to a list. You can just do `inputString = []` and `inputString.append(x)` instead of making it a string -- remember that string append is an O(N) operation since a completely new string needs to be built. 5. You loop `for i in inputList` and then _reset `inputList` inside that loop!_ This is a [code-smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) 6. Why do you need to reset `inputList` with the result of your translation? Why not make it a _new list_?

Comment: You'll find these links useful: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 0):

At first iteration you set

```py
inputList = list(inputStr)
# inputList = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
```

then you redefine it:

```py
inputList = [array[letter] for letter in inputList]
# inputList = ['Hotel', 'Echo', 'Lima', 'Lima', 'Oscar']
```

and you will get that error, since from this redefinition your next `i for-loop` will be over new inputList. So, you need to fix variable names to unique to fix this.

Also you've an error in punctList, it should be `r`-string or double backslash `\\` to escape that backslash:

```py
punctList = r"~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={[}]\|;:<,>.?/''"
```

otherwise it will get `\|` as `|` and tries to translate `\` too as allowed letter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tell the loop to break

```
for i in inputList:
    inputList = [array[letter] for letter in inputList]
    print(inputList)
    break
```

Alternatively, you could do away with the `for i in inputList` all together since you're iterating over the list already

```
def translateString(string, array):
    inputStr = ""

    punctList = "~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={[}]\|;:<,>.?/''"
    for x in string:
        if x not in punctList:
            inputStr = inputStr + x
            inputList = list(inputStr)

    inputList = [array[letter] for letter in inputList]
    print(inputList)
```

You'll also want to add a break for you loop check, otherwise it'll keep looping regardless of what you input

```
loop = raw_input("Would you like to translate another String?  Please press 'Y' to restart or another key to end.")
if loop.upper() != "Y":
    break
```

Otherwise it'll keep looping regardless of what you input